# Как прочитать переменную из формы PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Мне нужно прочитать переменную из виджета `lineEdit` и потом по кнопке выполнить функцию, в которой происходит вычисление с использованием той самой переменной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Загрузите страницу интерфейса
    uic.loadUi('ain.ui', self) #Загружаю форму
    A=self.lineEdit.text() #Пытаюсь прочитать переменную используя lineEdit
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plotBarChart) #Строчка, ответственная за выполнение функции по кнопке 

def plotBarChart(self):
   #Как здесь обозначить А? И выполнить с ней вычисление
   result = A*3.14
   return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # Загрузите страницу интерфейса
    uic.loadUi('ain.ui', self) #Загружаю форму
#    A = self.lineEdit.text()        #Пытаюсь прочитать переменную используя lineEdit
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plotBarChart) #Строчка, ответственная за выполнение функции по кнопке 

def plotBarChart(self):
   #Как здесь обозначить А? И выполнить с ней вычисление
#   result = A*3.14
   result = int(self.lineEdit.text()) * 3.14                              # +++
   return result
```

Comment: Как только не марочился с этой ерундой, даже когда вы написали, думал, что так уже делал и  не получится, но в итоге все работает) Спасибо большое